# How to log IdeaVIM normal mode commands

Tags: vim, ideavim

I'm constantly looking to improve my typing speed and text editing efficiency, as most of my fellow VIM users probably do.

To find out the best way to improve this, I'm looking for a way to see my most used commands in `normal` mode. I want to see the verbose commands that I use often, and then map it to a shortcut so I don't have to type it over and over again. For example, I've mapped `<leader>c` to `ciw`, because I use it very often.

Now I know it's possible to log **all** keystrokes with VIM, using `vim -w ~/path/to/vimlog.log`. I have found two solutions to make use of this log data, credits to http://www.drbunsen.org/vim-croquet/ and https://github.com/dstokes/vimlex for that.

The problem here is though, for coding I only use VIM in an IDE, like PyCharm and IntelliJ (exclusively IntelliJ IDEs), leading to my actual question. Is it possible to pass a 'command line' option (the -w) to this emulated IdeaVIM, so that every keystroke gets saved somewhere while I'm coding in IntelliJ platform IDEs?

An even more ideal solution would be to log only normal mode commands, as those are the only ones I'm interested in. Maybe it'd be a better idea for me to request this feature? Doesn't seem like a very hard one to implement, correct me if I'm wrong. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IdeaVim doesn't support it as the moment. Feel free to send a feature request to [its issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM) or even a pull request with your own implementation to [its page on GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply, and the awesome plugin which I use on a daily basis. Right now however, I do not have the time to dive into the code to make a useful addition. I may do this in the future. I've created the issue as a feature request.